# Heroku pipeline. Run commands on production app (not staging)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-console, heroku-postgres

I am using the heroku pipeline. I set up my two apps. One for staging, one for production. Both use "production" as the environment variable.

If I run `heroku run rails c` I can access the console on my staging app. The heroku website, allows to run a console in the production app as well, but only with the predifined `heroku run` part. Which means if for whatever reason I need to run a more fundamental command (for example `heroku pg:reset`; I know I know), I can't.

So is there a way to specify which heroku app I want to run the commands at? Something like `heroku pg:reset production-app-name` maybe?

I am using cloud9 as an IDE, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you got it almost right, just add `--app` before the `app-name`:

```
$ heroku pg:reset --app production-app-name
```

In fact, if you have more than one app configured (run `heroku apps` to list them), you will get an error; for example, try running a *safer* command:

```
$ heroku logs
```

If you have more than one app, the output will be:

```
 ▸    Error: Multiple apps in git remotes
 ▸    Usage: heroku logs --remote production
 ▸       or: heroku logs --app production-app-name
 ▸
 ▸    Your local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git remotes.
 ▸    Because of this, we can't determine which app you want to run this command against.
 ▸    Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.
 ▸
 ▸    Heroku remotes in repo:
 ▸    production      (production-app-name)
 ▸    staging         (staging-app-name)
 ▸
 ▸    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments
```

Comment: So I just have to add it as a remote and that's all?

Comment: @Tashows Yes, check [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) about setting multiple enviornments.

Comment: Thank you. I only needed to add the remote using this:
```git remote add live https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git```
Now it's working like you said. :)