# Django Heroku Robots.txt Exclude from Production Pipeline

Tags: python, django, heroku, robots.txt, production

I am testing out Pipelines on Heroku.

I have a staging app and a Production app in a  pipeline and I had two issues which arose at the same time, and so may or nor may not be interrelated....

The first was how to run commands from my CLI on both my staging and production app.

[This partially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251634/heroku-pipeline-run-commands-on-production-app-not-staging) answered my question but not entirely. I found the solution was to set my [staging app as the default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments): git config heroku.remote staging

Then to run my production apps commands I can run a command like so: heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser -a, --app your-app-name

The other issue which remains unresolved, seems to have a [solution for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813534/different-robots-txt-for-staging-server-on-heroku) is how to control my robots.txt from staging to production. I want my staging app to be hidden from Google indexing etc. but I don't want this to be transferred over to my production app (of course). Perhaps I shouldn't be using robots at all? Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: You should include the parts that are relevant from the links, because links might get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any suggestions, I created a solution for this problem, namely how to prevent indexing of a staging app by google when using Heroku pipelines.

The issue is when "promoting" your linked repo from staging to production there seemed to be no obvious way to prevent the staging app being indexed by search engines but whilst still ensuring your production app is indexed.

I decided on limiting all views via a middleware according to IP address. Now only specific IPs can access the staging app on heroku. Perhaps this is not the best way, but in the absence of any other answer, this seems to work:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
import os

def IPcheckMIddleware(get_response):

        def middleware(request, *args, **kwargs):
        herokuEnv = os.environ['IS_LIVE']
        if herokuEnv == 'FALSE':
            ip1=os.environ['IP_CHECKER']
            ip2=os.environ['IP_CHECKER_1']
            x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
            if x_forwarded_for:
                ips = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1]
            else:

                ips = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

            if ips in [ip1,ip2]:
                pass
            else:
                raise PermissionDenied
        else:
            pass

        response = get_response(request)


        return response

    return middleware
```

Hope that helps anyone with the same/similar issue...!